# Why does <xsl:for-each select="text()"> ignore blank spaces?

Tags: xslt

Why does `<xsl:for-each select="text()">` ignore blank spaces?

Example XML Source:

```
<body>
Things<note>such as people</note> <note>or animals</note>act in crazy ways.
</body>
```

Example XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="body">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="text()">
            <text>
                 <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
```

I would expect this output:

```
<output>
    <text>Things</text><text> </text><text>act in crazy ways.</text>
</output>
```

But what I get is this:

```
<output>
    <text>Things</text><text>act in crazy ways.</text>
</output>
```

Can someone give me some insight into how this works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that `<xsl:for-each>` ignores blank text nodes, but rather, whitespace-only text nodes may get stripped upon parsing the input document, before your stylesheet templates ever see them.

According to the XSLT spec, XSLT by default strips whitespace-only text nodes from the stylesheet document except in `<xsl:text>` elements; but does not strip them from the source document unless you use `<xsl:strip-space>`.

The [XSLT 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#strip) describes it this way:

> After the tree for a source document
>   or stylesheet document has been
>   constructed, but before it is
>   otherwise processed by XSLT, some text
>   nodes are stripped. A text node is
>   never stripped unless it contains only
>   whitespace characters. Stripping the
>   text node removes the text node from
>   the tree. The stripping process takes
>   as input a set of element names for
>   which whitespace must be preserved.
>   The stripping process is applied to
>   both stylesheets and source documents,
>   but the set of whitespace-preserving
>   element names is determined
>   differently for stylesheets and for
>   source documents.
>
> A text node is preserved if any of the
>   following apply:
>
> - The element name of the parent of the text node is in the set of whitespace-preserving element names.
> - The text node contains at least one non-whitespace character. As in XML, a whitespace character is #x20, #x9, #xD or #xA.
> - An ancestor element of the text node has an xml:space attribute with a value of preserve, and no closer ancestor element has xml:space with a value of default.
>
> Otherwise, the text node is stripped.
>
> The xml:space attributes are not
>   stripped from the tree.
>
> NOTE: This implies that if an xml:space attribute is specified on a
>   literal result element, it will be
>   included in the result.
>
> For stylesheets, the set of
>   whitespace-preserving element names
>   consists of just xsl:text.
>
> For source documents, the set of
>   whitespace-preserving element names is
>   specified by xsl:strip-space and
>   xsl:preserve-space top-level elements. These elements each have an elements attribute whose value is a whitespace-separated list of NameTests. **Initially, the set of whitespace-preserving element names contains all element names.** [emphasis mine] If an element name matches a NameTest in an xsl:strip-space element, then it is removed from the set of whitespace-preserving element names. If an element name matches a NameTest in an xsl:preserve-space element, then it is added to the set of whitespace-preserving element names.

So in summary, the stripping should not be happening with your source document... unless you are using the `<xsl:strip-space>` top-level element in your stylesheet. If you are not using `<xsl:strip-space>`, please tell us more about your XSLT processor, and your top-level stylesheet elements.

According to [this article](http://xmlplease.com/whitespace), not every XSLT processor respects the default behavior described in the spec. You might try adding the following as a child of `<xsl:stylesheet>`, and see if it fixes the problem:

```
<xsl:preserve-space elements="*"/>
```

Comment: @LarsH: In fact, there are different choices from every XSLT processor. Relevant part of your own link: http://xmlplease.com/whitespace#s7.

Comment: @Alej, right... I should have clarified that I was describing what the spec says. However that is why I included the link and asked what processor the OP was using.

Comment: But I am using <xsl:preserve-space elements="*" />

Comment: @joe: OK. I assume you're going to tell us more about your XSLT processor and version?

Comment: Nevermind I found an instance of <xsl:strip-space> that I did not comment out. Thanks!

Comment: @Joe: The too-minimal XSL example strikes again. Glad you found the problem.

Comment: @LarsH: As you see (your emphasis), the specs could be missundertood. From all the above white space only text node from input source may be stripped, except for that sentence (sort of lost in there) that declare a `xsl:preserve-space elements="*"` by default.

Comment: @Alej: I agree, it's not easy to see. But I would expect implementors of a spec, especially those developing major development tools, to be more strict than that... and I believe the spec is unambiguous when read carefully. I would expect the implementors to run their processors through some conformance tests too. But hey, Saxon works and that's what I use so I'm happy enough. :-)

Comment: @LarsH: I wish your hopes makes true, ja! +1 For quoting the specs, also.

Comment: @Alej, I was just reading in Kay's XSLT 2.0 book 4th edition that Altova has been criticized as not very conformant, but he says that as of 2008 it "has very few restrictions that are likely to affect the typical user". However, he says that Altova "warns you about significant differences in behavior" "in the area of whitespace handling." Essentially, it still strips whitespace nodes from the source doc, and doesn't offer a way to turn that off!

Comment: @LarsH: Yes! See they solution recomendation in http://manual.altova.com/XMLSpy/spystandard/index.html?xslt1engineimplementation.htm

Comment: @Alej: unbelievable: They tell you to modify the source XML. :-p Unbelievable that they haven't fixed it yet after all this time. Maybe they don't really expect people to use their own processor.

Answer (score 3):

There are differents choices made from every XSLT processor (in fact from the XML tree provider) about white space only text nodes from input source.

Most of them (the most that count...) respect the `xsl:preserve-space` instruction.

Comment: Good point. +1  Let the reader understand that XMLSpy's homegrown processor and Stylus Studio's are not among those "that count"... or weren't at the time that article was written. (http://xmlplease.com/whitespace#s7.)